# Using the Model instead of the Controller for checking if data already exists for a user

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

So I wrote a flag feature for flagging comments, and I'm checking in my controller to see if the user has already flagged a particular comment. The problem is, I think this can be done in the Model.

The function is:

```
private function userAlreadyFlagged($userId, $commentId) {
    $userAlreadyFlagged = $this->CommentsFlag->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array('CommentsFlag.comment_id' => $commentId, 'CommentsFlag.user_id' => $userId)
            ));

    if ($userAlreadyFlagged > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I have another function also within the controller called `flagComment`

```
if (!$this->userAlreadyFlagged($userId, $commentId)) {
    if ($this->CommentsFlag->save($this->request->data)) {
        $message = array('response' => 'success');
    }
} else {
    $message = array('response' => 'alreadyFlagged');
}​
```

My model for the CommentsFlag current links my `users` table to it:

```
var $name = 'CommentsFlag';
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User'
    )
);
```

So I'm wondering how I can start doing stuff like this in the model from now on, because I have a lot of code like this that would be better suited for the Model.

Comment: why is it private? firstly a method in your project should never be private (only protected) as it goes against a framework idea. secondly you might want to access it from a controller some day - so public would not hurt either, probably

Comment: Well it was only being called from within that controller, which is why I made it private. It's moved to the model and public now, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to have fat-models. What problem are you facing in moving the above functions to model?

Copy those functions into your model (CommentsFlag) and replace all `$this->CommentsFlag->find(...` with `$this->find(`

Consequently, to call above functions from your model, you can use:

`$this->CommentsFlag->userAlreadyFlagged()` if called from CommentsFlag's controller

or
`$this->User->CommentsFlag->userAlreadyFlagged()` if called from User's controller.

Comment: Nice, thanks. So what should the controller be doing then? Would some of this be able to go into the Model? http://pastebin.com/uYAupums